# iCloud Drive REST API?

Tags: rest, icloud, cloudkit, icloud-drive

I'm writing Windows C++ application that gives user ability to save some work results directly to cloud storage like Google Drive, Dropbox and OneDrive. I've been able to create working implementation of code that uses OAuth2 and REST API to authenticate user and upload files (with CppRestSDK help).
Now i've been searching for ability to do the same with iCloud Drive service. So far i've seen that for all (?) iCloud based services Apple gives CloudKit SDK to work with them. But this SDK is available ony for XCode and there is some web version for JavaScript.
My question is simple - is there any way to upload files to iCloud Drive from Windows C++ application?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately - no. We gave up on this.

Comment: https://github.com/MauriceConrad/iCloud-API and https://github.com/picklepete/pyicloud so it must be possible...