# How to connect to iCloud Drive via rest API?

Tags: c#, ios, rest, uwp, icloud-drive

I'm developing an application written in C# (UWP) and it seems no ready-to-use sdk is available for managing the interaction with iCloud drive (get items, create items, upload items...).
Hence, I want to implement a custom iCloud drive client via rest API (in C#).
I already tested the "Sign in with Apple REST API" approach and it's almost working.

Now I need to find a "clear" Apple API documentation to perform all of the operations on iCloud drive.
Is there any official link?
Can you provide some simple examples on how to query iCloud drive in pure rest, for example to get all of the items in a folder?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Enzo, did you manage to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears a REST interface is still not available for iCloud Drive.

[iCloud Drive REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278093/icloud-drive-rest-api)